# I have a dataframe where some index number are missing how do I cut dataframe previous to that missing index number

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

[enter image description here][1]

Index number 72 is missing from original dataframe which is shown in image. I want to cut dataframe like [0:71,:] with condition like when index sequence breaks then dataframe automatically cuts from previous index value.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Compare shifted values of index subtracted by original values if greater like `1` with invert ordering by `[::-1]` and [`Series.cummax`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.cummax.html), last filter in [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': range(3,13)}).drop(3)
print (df)
    a
0   3
1   4
2   5
4   7
5   8
6   9
7  10
8  11
9  12

df = df[df.index.to_series().shift(-1, fill_value=0).sub(df.index).gt(1)[::-1].cummax()]
print (df)
   a
0  3
1  4
2  5
```

Answer (score 1):

i came to this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col':[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]}, index=[-1,0,1,2,3,4,5,7,8])

ind = next((i for i in range(len(df)-1) if df.index[i]+1!=df.index[i+1]),len(df))+1

>>> df.iloc[:ind]
'''
    col
-1    1
 0    2
 1    3
 2    4
 3    5
 4    6
 5    7
```

Comment: Nice one, I had a [similar approach in mind](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73658590/16343464), using numpy ;)

Answer (score 1):

With [numpy](/questions/tagged/numpy), get the values that are equal to a normal range starting from the first index, up to the first mismatch (excluded):

```
df[np.minimum.accumulate(df.index==np.arange(df.index[0], df.index[0]+len(df)))]
```

Example:

```
    col
-1    1
 0    2
 1    3
 3    4
 4    5
```

output:

```
    col
-1    1
 0    2
 1    3
```